# How do I prevent zero in a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class where the template parameter corresponds to the size of an array within the class.

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t S>
class Example {
    ...

 private:
    T values[S];
};
```

This leads to an expected warning: “ISO C++ forbids zero-size array.” In my case, something like `Example<uint8_t, 0>` would make no sense, and I would like to prevent the code containing `Example<..., 0>` from compiling.

How do I express in C++ that `S` should be superior or equal to one?

Comment: If there are situations where S can be zero then you can template partial specialization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're really trading in one compiler diagnostic for another, but here's one approach:

```
template <typename T, size_t S,
      typename=std::enable_if_t< (S>0) >>
```

Alternatively: use `static_assert` to get a friendlier error message:

```
template <typename T, size_t S>
class Example {

 private:

    static_assert(S>0);
    T values[S];
};
```

You'll get a friendlier error message however this template will still participate in overload resolution, which in some edge cases may be undesirable.

Comment: An evil programmer can circumvent this by passing a custom argument to the third parameter. A more robust version is `std::enable_if_t<(S>0), std::nullptr_t> = nullptr`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's not evil, it's self-sabotage.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat -- an evil programmer deserves whatever happens to them.

Comment: Less verbose error message if you put the static assert in a partial template specialization; template <typename T>
class Example<T, 0> {
 static_assert(false, "You are not allowed to use a zero sized buffer");
};

Answer (score 10):

The C++20 way is

```
template <typename T, size_t S> requires (S > 0)
class Example
{
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 4):

`T values[0];` is alread ill-formed. Thus, if you configure the compiler to not use language extensions, then it won't compile.

Or, you can use a `static_assert`.

Answer (score 2):

If there are situations where S being zero are valid. You can add a specialization for that case.

```
template<typename T, size_t S>
class Example {
    ...

 private:
    T values[S];
};

template<typename T>
class Example<T, 0> {
    ...
    private:
    // Don't need an array here for this case.
};
```

This will keep your code compiling in situations where you have heavy templating that makes S zero.